# R or RStudio on OX X 10.9 suddenly request X11 installation

Tags: r, macos, x11, rstudio

Since some days I always get a message when working with R and RStudio, telling that "to open R, you must install X11". This is strange because I'm working since "ages" with R and RStudio, and also the current configuration (R 3.1.2 and RStudio 0.99.283 on OS X 10.9.5) runs since some weeks without any troubles.

Does anybody know what I could do? Reinstall R / RStudio?

Comment: Did you restart your computer?

Comment: Do you have X11 installed? What's stopping you from installing it?

Comment: maybe you had X11 before and it broke?

Comment: @Pascal yes, I restarted my  computer twice since this "bug".

Comment: @Roland I just seem to have the installer-app. When I click on that icon, a popup appears saying "An app requested access to X11, do you want to install it now?". I'm just curious why I suddenly need X11, when everything worked fine for months... And as I wrote, I haven't changed my config, installed or removed anything special etc.

Comment: I can't find a reference online, but as I recall from last installing RStudio three months ago  X11 is required. Maybe there was an OS update or X11 broke for other reasons. I recommend asking at the RStudio support forum.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I guess I simply install X11 and maybe also ask the RStudio support. I just didn't want to install more software than necessary. :-)

Comment: Could it be that certain packages require X11? The pop up showed up again after I loaded some packages via 'library'.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I stumbled over an ggplot2-issue [at GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1064), which might explain the behaviour (a bug in the colorspace package).

I'll try to install the previous version on my Mac later and check whether this really solves the problem...